# How to set the parameter values for ARX model

Tags: dynamic, time, system, series, forecasting

There are two time series, "A"(auto-regressive variable) and "B"(exogenous variable).

Please let me know how to estimate the parameters for auto-regressive variable after fixing the parameter values for exogenous variable. Such that,

First set the parameter values for exogenous variable and then find the parameters for auto-regressive variable

Thanking you in advance,

Kushan

Answer (score 1):

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Hi Kushan, I attached the answer

Simone

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]